# How do I know if the stdout data of a child process has been broken down to buffer chunks?

Tags: node.js, buffer, child-process

So, when working with child processes in node.js, we are reading stdout of a child process from buffer stream. So, how do I know if a buffer chunk contains the full stdout message or only a part of it? How do I know if a chunk is the last one? Or is this  impossible (I suspect the answer YES, but I hope that it is NO)?

I am asking this because in my case parent and child processes communicate by sending JSON to each other, and I should know when the JSON actually ends, and when it is broken apart. I could run JSON.parse every time and see if it is a valid JSON, but this seems smelly to me.

Answer (score 0):

If someone finds it useful, including me in future, we could append some token like `<EOM>` i.e. [End Of Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_message) to a JSON message, so that we could know that it is the end of the whole message even if the message was broken down to chunks. And when receiving `data` chunks we just check if a chunk ends with `<EOM>`.